# full calendar touch screen support for external events

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, fullcalendar, touch, jquery-ui-touch-punch

The current version of fullcalendar works great on touch screens, you can drag and drop events within the calendar.  However the external dragging demo does not work.

https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.6.2/demos/external-dragging.html

Is there a way to get it to work?  I tried adding the jQueryUI Touch Punch library, which made it work in some mobile browsers but not all of them.

Comment: external dragging is enabled by jQueryUI's "draggable" functionality, not by fullCalendar directly. Have you checked about touch support for that?

Comment: The latest full calendar does dragging of events inside the calendar without using jQuery, and it works really well on touch screens.  So maybe there is some way to do the external events demo without using jQuery.

Comment: The docs (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dropping/) explicitly talk about the use of jQueryUI draggables, so I doubt it. There are various possibilities regarding enabling touch for jQueryUI draggable, as well as explanations of why it's like that, including the Touch Punch library which you've tried: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=jquery+ui+draggable+touch+support&oq=jquery+ui+draggable+touch+support&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2.5830j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 . Would be interesting to know which browser it doesn't work with. Perhaps they simply don't have the underlying support themselves?

Comment: Using touch punch, external dragging doesn't work in the default Samsung browser on my android phone, but works fine if I use Google Chrome instead.  However dragging within the calendar works great in the Samsung browser.  My guess is that fullcalendar is now using native html 5 drag and drop for internal dragging rather than jquery. https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/

Comment: "My guess is that fullcalendar is now using native html 5 drag and drop for internal dragging". You don't need to guess... if you read the documentation it tells you directly that interal drag/drop doesn't require jQuery: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_ui/Requirements/